# Apis Rest para e-commerce

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api, e-commerce

Estou tentando montar um e-commerce com um amigo e estamos pensando em montar uma api rest para acessar o bando de dados e em criar um site e um aplicativo para consumi-la. Como se trata de um e-commerce , gostaria de saber se as APIs Rest servem para cadastrar e logar um usuário no sistema.

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Talvez você devesse reformular um pouco melhor sua pergunta pra ela não acabar sendo fechada por ser ampla demais, qual o nivel da sua duvida ? sobre como criar um api ? sobre qual framework ou ferramenta usar ? e sim, API's rest servem para isso, você pode inclusive utilizar frameworks de front e back combinados, um bom exemplo disso é a combinação de API rest em Laravel com VueJS, explique um pouco melhor qual a sua dúvida, assim eu ou outra pessoa podemos responder com assertividade.

Comment: A minha dúvida essa justamente essa. Se era possível  fazer um login e um cadastro de usuário usando uma api rest. Não tenho dúvidas sobre como criar uma api. E nem sobre ferramentas. Ainda estamos pensando em como o sistema vai funcionar, ainda decidimos em que vamos desenvolvê-lo.

Comment: Ah, então o comentário resolveu sua duvida ? recomendo usar o Laravel pra esse tipo de produto se for utilizar em PHP, só confirme se pretende fazer isso em PHP, ai posso preparar um resposta boa.

Comment: Estamos pensando em usar Django ou Laravel. Como essas operações seriam feitas em Laravel?

Comment: Estou preparando uma resposta completa pra te ajudar, ja ja posto ela ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, inicie o projeto:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel sua-api
```

Entre na pasta:

```
cd sua-api
```

Após isso, será necessário criar a autenticação, pra isso use o comando:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Esse comando irá criar um série de arquivos `.blade` `resourcer/view/auth` e `resources/view/auth/passwords`, criará mais um `Controller` e uma `Model` que automatizará seu processo de login, também, irá adicionar dentro de seu arquivo `api.php` duas linhas:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Agora você irá precisar colocar suas rotas dentro de um `middleware`, esse arquivo deverá ter a seguinte configuração de rotas:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect()->to('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login');
    });

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

Pra você poder logar, ira precisar ter uma tabela com os usuários e a chave de memória da autenticação (remember_token),  para isso use o comando:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

Após isso, abra a `migration` que foi gerada na pasta `database/migrations`, e deixe a função `up` da seguinte forma:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('name', 32);
        $table->string('username', 32);
        $table->string('email', 320);
        $table->string('password', 64);
        $table->string('remember_token', 100)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

Execute a migração:

```
php artisan migrate
```

E por fim, inicie seu servidor do projeto:

```
php artisan serve
```

Agora, acesse:

```
https://127.0.0.8000/
```

Você será redirecionado a uma pagina padrão de login do `Laravel`, nesta página no canto esquerdo superior poderá registar usuários, após cadastrar o mesmo, faça o login, deverá ser redirecionado a uma `Home` padrão do `Laravel` também.

Partindo disso, podes alterar todo os templates gerados como quiser, e passar usar as demais funções.

Para verificar se um usuário está logado e tem permissão para executar funções nos métodos criados posteriormente use o segunte comando em suas models:

```
 Auth::check()
```

Deverá responder `true` ou `false`.

Isso deve ser o suficiente para iniciar o seu projeto.